# How to reduce lambda calculus

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I try to understand lambda calculus and read the wonderful [article](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/ag-ki/rojas_home/documents/tutorials/lambda.pdf).

On the page 8, there is an expression:

```
(λy.(x(λx.xy)))
```

If I am going to substitute the left outer most`(λy)` with `t`,

```
(λy.(x(λx.xy))) t
```

then the result would be?

```
x(λx.xy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of rewriting it to haskell syntax

```
(\y -> x (\x-> x y))
(\y -> x (\x-> x y)) t

x (\x -> x t)
```

since the y is already bound to the input \y all y will be substituted by t.

Edit: As noted in the comment below if t where to contain a free x it would be important to rename the bound x in this scope to a "fresh" name. That is a name that has currently no meaning. If we say

```
let t = \t -> x t
```

Then the proper substitution would look like

```
x (\z -> z (\t -> x t))
```

Where as stated by `pigworker` some `z` is chosen for freshness as a fresh identifier to replace our bound x to prevent hiding the free x in t.

Comment: Any free occurrences of x in t will be incorrectly captured by the above reduction. The \x -> x t might more safely become \z -> z t, where z has been chosen for freshness.